# access GameObject by name and perform setActive(false) operation in unity3d

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get access to a specific object `cylinder` under the `hallway` as shown in the hierarchy view image below. I am using the following script to get a reference to the object but I get a `null pointer exception`:

```
GameObject cylinder = GameObject.Find("/hallway/Cylinder");
```

[image]

Comment: In your question there is no image attached...

Comment: Do you REALLY need to get it by name ? It's really inneficient and you should use setting via editor if you can. If your script is on the parent of the object you want to find, you can also use GetChilds() to parse less gameobjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) to find the inactive GameObject.

```
GameObject FindGameObject(string name, string parentName = "")
{
    foreach (GameObject go in Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])
    {
        if (go.name == name)
        {
            if (parentName == "" || go.transform.parent.name == parentName)
                return go;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
GameObject cylinder = FindGameObject("Cylinder");
```

or

```
GameObject cylinder = FindGameObject("Cylinder","hallway");
```

Comment: Doesn't work using the path name for longer paths. Also be sure to ignore Prefabs.